# Symfony FileType form field returns NULL

Tags: forms, symfony, upload

I have a form where you upload an image, but whenever I submit the file variable in the controller is said to be NULL. I don't get any errors.

```
/** @var UploadedFile $businessCardFile */
$businessCardFile = $report_form->get('businesscardimg')->getData();
```

entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $businesscardimg;


...


public function getBusinesscardimg(): ?string
    {
        return $this->businesscardimg;
    }

    public function setBusinesscardimg(?string $businesscardimg): self
    {
        $this->businesscardimg = $businesscardimg;

        return $this;
    }
```

form:

```
->add('businesscardimg', FileType::class, [
                'row_attr' => ['id' => 'businesscardimg'],
                'required'   => false,
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Business Card Photo'
                ),
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'image/png',
                            'image/PNG',
                            'image/jpeg',
                            'image/jpg',
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid Image',
                    ])
                ],
            ])
```

controller:

```
if ($report_form->isSubmitted()) {
            $report = $report_form->getData();

            /** @var UploadedFile $businessCardFile */
            $businessCardFile = $report_form->get('businesscardimg')->getData();
```

At this point $businessCardFile is already NULL.
Every other field of the form works except this one. I have a div that displays the uploaded image's file name and that works, but once you submit the image isn't saved.

```
const fileSelector = document.getElementById('visitor_report_businesscardimg');
        const filenamePreview = document.getElementById('filename-preview');
        fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            const fileList = event.target.files;
            filenamePreview.innerHTML = fileList[0].name;
        });
```

Comment: I just added $report_form->isValid() as a condition and I found I have an error on the form. It says: ERROR: This form should not contain extra fields. But I have no idea what to do with that.

Comment: Just added "allow_extra_fields" => true to the formtype and now it is valid and tried var_dumping $report_form->getExtraData() and it says: array(6) { ["name"]=> array(1) { ["businesscardimg"]=> string(23) "rewind-button-round.png" } ["full_path"]=> array(1) { ["businesscardimg"]=> string(23) "rewind-button-round.png" } ["type"]=> array(1) { ["businesscardimg"]=> string(9) "image/png" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { ["businesscardimg"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php6AF4.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { ["businesscardimg"]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { ["businesscardimg"]=> int(12572) } }